# como guardar una imagen en el servidor mediante una API que recibe la imagen en byte[]. C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Saludo. Estoy trabajando con Winform consumiento una API .net core 3.1,  desde Winform tengo el modelo cliente que tiene la propiedad `public byte[] imagen { get; set; }` .

en el API quiero agarrar esa imagen guardarla en los archivos y guardar la ruta en la base de datos.

primera ve que intento hacer esto.

me he querido guiar por un estas recomendaciones que encontré:

*Cargar un archivo, almacenarlo en el sistema de archivos local y guardarlo en una base de datos es un patrón común. Estas son mis recomendaciones.

1. No utilice el nombre de archivo cargado como su nombre de archivo.
   Esto es común:

   var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

   var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Photo/"), filename);
   file.SaveAs(path);

No lo hagas. Hay unas pocas razones:

a) Los nombres de archivo pueden entrar en conflicto.
b) Los nombres de archivos remotos pueden ser incompatibles con su sistema de archivos local.
c) Alguien puede probar un nombre de archivo malicioso y hacer esto puede dañar su servidor.

En su lugar, genere su propio nombre de archivo (quizás usando un `GUID` ) y almacene el nombre de archivo original en su base de `datos.GUID.NewGuid().ToString()`

2. No almacene todos los archivos en una sola carpeta
   En algún momento, su carpeta contendrá demasiados archivos para que el sistema operativo los procese rápidamente.
   Divida los archivos por algo útil, como el ID de usuario. Esto también ayuda a segregar los archivos entre usuarios.
3. No almacene la ruta completa al archivo en la base de datos
   En algún momento, puede mover los archivos (quizás a una unidad diferente) y todas las ubicaciones de los archivos almacenados se romperán.
4. No almacene la URL de la imagen en la base de datos.
   Igual que el n. ° 3. Si su aplicación web cambia y desea cambiar las URL de la imagen, entonces tiene URL incorrectas almacenadas en la base de datos. Tendrá que escanear y actualizar todos los registros de su base de datos.
5. No almacene información de ruta redundante en la base de datos
   Si bien puede resultar tentador incluir `"Cargas / Foto /"` en la URL almacenada en la base de datos, también presenta muchos problemas:

a) Son datos redundantes. Para cada archivo, está utilizando espacio de datos adicional e innecesario.
b) Si su aplicación cambia y la URL debería cambiar, sus URL almacenadas ahora están dañadas.

En su lugar, anteponga `"Cargas / Foto /"` a la URL después de leer el valor de la base de datos.*

incluso me da el siguiente ejemplo que para mi no funciona:

ya que la imagen la obtengo de un  `PictureBox` y la convierto a byte[] para mandarla en el modelo.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EventModel eventmodel, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var originalFilename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        string fileId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");
        string userId = GetUserId(); // Function to get user id based on your schema

        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Photo/"), userId, fileId);
        file.SaveAs(path);

        eventModel.ImageId = fileId;
        eventmodel.OriginalFilename = originalFilename;

        _db.EventModels.AddObject(eventmodel);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
    
    return View(eventmodel);

}
```

En fin lo que hago en mi proyecto winform es agarrar la imagen del `PictureBox` y convertirla a byte[] y creo un `objeto` de tipo `cliente` que tiene la siguiente propiedad: `public byte[] imagen { get; set; }` y mando ese objeto a la API mediante una petición `Http POST`.

Lo que quiero hacer en la API y obtener ese objeto tomar la imagen que viene en la propiedad `public byte[] imagen { get; set; }` y convertir para guardarla en una capeta del servidor cumpliendo con 4 de los 5 recomendación que mención mas arriba.

El único requerimiento que no deseo cumplir es que guarde los tipos de archivos en carpetas diferentes.

Comment: Puedes reducir la pregunta y quitar información redundante. Especificando cual es el inconveniente que tienes y que esperas que haga el Código.  Puedes leer la sección de [como hacer preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Recuerda que esta comunidad es para responder dudas o problemas específicos. No para hacer la tarea o el trabajo de otra persona.

Comment: Si quieres hacer referencia a un articulo o documentación, puedes [poner un enlace](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link) a dicho articulo. Tambien puedes [poner una cita](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#blockquote) al articulo.